# window.location after animate

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, window.location

first time I ask a question over here but I have a problem...

Here you can find the HTML:

```
 <aside class="aside-smart">            


           <ul class="nav-asside">                    
                <li><a href="about.html" class=" l-aside-link" id="about">About</a>  </li>
                <li><a href="work.html" class="l-aside-link color-animate"   id="work">Work</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html" class="l-aside-link"   id="contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="icon-twitter l-aside-link"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="icon-behance l-aside-link"></a></li>            
            </ul>
   <aside>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$("#about").click(function(){

        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("ok");          

    $("aside").animate({left:'0'},1000,function(){

       // window.location=$("#about").attr("href");
          window.location = "about.html";       

        });         
    });
});
```

In the CSS I said to my aside to be at 40% from left of the screen side with a position fixed (useful for the rest of the website). So nothing wrong in the CSS I think.

**What I want to do :**

When I click on one of the link (About or Work or Contact). The aside first go to "left=0" and then go to the original URL.

**how I proceed**

So at first I began to put a `event.preventDefault` and then I asked to jQuery to target the "aside" to move to left=0 and then go to the URL.

I got no errors in the console... but when I click on one of the links, it doesn't do the animation.

if I comment the window.location line, then the animation has no problem to move the aside. But I don't go the URL...

So I don't understand where the problem is... ? I have no error in the console ?

I'm also a beginner in jQuery so maybe is the answer very easy. And at least if there is a proper way to write this "link comportement" I'm curious to learn about it.

Thanks a lot for the responses :)

Have a nice day.

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle with all of your code.

Comment: @user3719947 - I think it's `window.location.href` (the 'window.' is not necessary)

Comment: @user3719947 - also, if you use `event.preventDefault();`, it's good practice to supply the event as argument in the function: `$("#about").click(function(e){e.preventDefault();});` (used 'e' instead of 'event', but that's not necessary obviously)

Comment: @user3719947 - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp

Comment: here is the [Js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t6DPy/)

Comment: @Ol-VT whats up with the fiddle it works nah ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing event in function as suggested in comments does work.

Original by [myfunkyside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24107834/window-location-after-animate#comment37188968_24107834):
if you use `event.preventDefault();`, it's good practice to supply the event as argument in the function: `$("#about").click(function(e){e.preventDefault();});` (used '`e`' instead of '`event`', but that's not necessary obviously)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t6DPy/1/)

**Edit** Clarification for slow performance:

-conflict with transition by css, causing the animation to be stuttering or not shown.

Removing the transition from css will speed up the animation, but animation does not run smooth.

```
aside { 
    position: fixed; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    z-index: 500; 
    width: 20%; 
    height: 100%; 
    background: #1a1a1a; 
    /*-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out; 
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out; 
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out; 
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;*/ 
}
```

Full code edit to improve animation performance:

```
aside { 
    position: fixed; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    z-index: 500; 
    width: 20%; 
    height: 100%; 
    background: #1a1a1a; 
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out; 
    -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in-out; 
    -o-transition: all 2s ease-in-out; 
    transition: all 2s ease-in-out; 
}
```

Change in main.js:

```
$("#aside").animate({left:0},2000, function(){
    //window.location=$("#contact").attr("href");
    window.location = "contact.html";   
});
```

to

```
$("#aside").css({left:0});
setTimeout( function() {
    window.location = "contact.html";
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Hey could you please explain what the is OP question

Comment: Okay but even if it works in the Js fiddle when I test it on google chrome (in local) it doesn't work. The aside doesn't move but after the 2s or 1s of the animate I go on the correct link. So I don't know where is the bug :/

Comment: @Ol-VT did you copy and test my fiddle in local files? Don't forget to add in the missing html code that links to jquery.

Comment: Yep I just test it. I copied your code. And create a link before the </body>

<script>js/jquery.js</script>
<script>js/main.js</script>

and there are no consol errors :'(

Comment: @Ol-VT `<script>js/jquery.js</script>` is wrong! It needs to be `<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>`

Comment: Oh yep sorry that's what I wrote... >O< 

Yep I just put in on a webhost and the bug or the problem is still there. I really don't get it and don't where it come from.

Comment: @Ol-VT can you give the link to where it can be found online?

Comment: When I click I see that the page is currently waiting for 2 seconds (time of the animation) but she doesn't show it.

Comment: @Ol-VT Confirm that my fiddle works in your chrome browser. Provide a link to the not working version of your code that you put on your webhost to test. I'm quite confident your implementation has errors, which I can not tell without seeing your full code sample.

Comment: @Ol-VT I think it's a performance issue. Try giving an id to your aside element and apply the animation to that id instead of the element. You also use an svg instead of a png/jpg. Try using a png instead and see if that improves speed. In firefox you can see the animation stuttering, in chrome there is only the jump.

Comment: @Anima-t3d I comment the tag with the Svg and put a Id on my aside (named : aside ) and it doesn't works on chrome and firefox it begin to slide but he never go to the end.

So if you say it work on your side, i will clean up all my browers and try again, at least the only solution that I see.

Thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: @Ol-VT Update the code online as well so we can help you.

Comment: well i put the index.html (with the svg in comment) online. But it still doesn't work on my side.

Comment: @Ol-VT change `$("aside").animate({left:'0'},2000,function(){` to effectively use an id: `$("#aside").animate({left:'0'},2000,function(){` note the added `#` to indicate the id selector.

Comment: @Anima-t3d sorry i forgot to upload the js file. Well it's online now :)

Comment: @Ol-VT I think the bad performance is caused by your css transition code on the aside (put in comment and it'll run faster): `aside {
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 500;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #1a1a1a;
  /*-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;*/
}`

Comment: I updated my answer to better show the answers to your question(s).

Comment: Well it's working now, many many thanks for this solution :) (i didn't find an other way to thank you :) )

Comment: @Ol-VT don't forget to accept my answer if it worked for you. You can now also remove the link to your online test in your previous comment.